# Как подключать интерфейсы php?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, интерфейс

Авторитетные книги, да и программисты, участвующие в проектировании средних и крупных проектов не дадут соврать: Проектируют на основе интерфейсов, затем создают тесты.

И уже на основе интерфейсов пишут реализацию.
Подключение классов хорошо написано в учебниках и мануалах. Обычно это автозагрузка(названия файлов и классов совпадают) + пространство имен, чтобы не возникали конфликты в соседних проектах.

Зашел на php.net - прочел про [автозагрузку](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.autoload.php):
"Попытка автоматически загрузить используемый, но не загруженный ранее, класс"
Ни словом про интерфейс.

Пример:

```
namespace MyDir\Classes

use MyDir\Classes\C

class B implements A
{
    protected $c;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->c = C::init();
    }
    public function doSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

Из этого пример видно в какой папке хранится класс B( в такой же что и класс С)
А вот как организовать хранение и чтение интерфейсов? Уже экспериментируя с подключениями интерфейсов столкнулся с тем что им тоже нужно пространство имен.
Как работают с подключением интерфейсов во фреймворке(например Symfony)? Подскажите ссылку на книгу по проектированию - где это(хранение и централизованное подключение интерфейсов) рассматривается. Если я правильно понял бессмысленно интерфейсы хранить в файле класса, потому как другим классам тоже может понадобится этот интерфейс

Comment: Хорошая книга "PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования"

Comment: Интерфейсы в PHP в разрезе автоподгрузки - это те же классы

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Это моя настольная книга, @zesen. Собственно прочтя ее у меня и возник этот вопрос, следовательно ответа я там не нашел